# Installing Vaadin Charts Trial License in Intellij Idea, Windows platform

Tags: intellij-idea, vaadin, vaadin-charts

As the Book of Vaadin explains I added the maven repository;

```
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-charts</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But the resolving becomes unsuccessful for  2.0.0 so I used 1.0.0 which was successful.
I got the TRIAL license key from vaadin but I cannot find a way to install it. My IDE is intellij Idea and im using windows 8. When i deploy the tutorial in the book of vaadin without the license i get the following error.

HTTP Status 500 - com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Series

Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the noclassdeffound error is not related to the licence.  your widgetset will not compile, if you lack the license.  it is more likely, that your example code does not match with your version.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a way to add the license or add the 2.0.0 version with maven?

Comment: you mean, like the documentation? https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/charts.installing.html

Comment: Well it doesn't work in my scenario as I have mentioned above. It doesn't get resolved. Thanks anyways.!

Comment: Tried a maven clean & install? I've noticed a similar error at work before.

Comment: Yes Now it works. Looks like its a maven resolve issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the issue by starting the vaading project using Maven in intellij idea. I didnt go for the Vaadin application but went for a new project using vaadin maven repo.

It downloaded the needed resources through the repo. And I ran the package maven goal to get my widget set compiled.

as to the licensing problem I had, It was solved by placing the licence key in a file named .vaadin.chartsdeveloper.license inside my home
that is in windows, : C:\Users\username

Now all is working fine.